# Issue with Newtonsoft JSON Serialization to Lower Camel Case

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm currently facing difficulties in converting object properties to lower camel case using Newtonsoft JSON serialization in C#. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
[JsonObject(Title = "booking")]
public class BookingJsonModel
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("reference")]
    public string Reference { get; set; } = null!;
    //...
}
```

and I have also tried to declare a property:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "reference")]
public string Reference { get; set; } = null!;
```

During serialization, I'm attempting to convert property names to lower camel case using the following code:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, settings);
```

Despite setting the ContractResolver to `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()`, the properties remain unchanged and still start with an upper case letter. It seems like both the ContractResolver and JsonProperty attributes are being ignored during serialization.

Could someone provide guidance or suggest an alternative approach to ensure the serialization of object properties to lower camel case using Newtonsoft JSON library in C#? Any insights or resolutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Simply works see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ss3CHW

Comment: Your code with `JsonProperty` should work fine. Check if all your involved types correctly resolve to the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace. Because some of the types are named the same in the .net builtin `System.Text.Json` and if they resolve to the wrong assembly they won't be used correctly.

Comment: In addition to @Ralf here is a fiddle that demonstrates also the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` working fine https://dotnetfiddle.net/YzAHCZ  But one thing to consider: If you have both, a contract resolver and a `JsonProperty` annotation, the latter will always "win" ...

Answer (score 0):

The

```
[JsonProperty("some name")]
public string SomeName {get;set;}
```

maps the property name in the raw JSON string, "some name" to the SomeName property in your class definition.

If you have defined your class to use the Property name "SomeName" the upper case on your model is what JSON maps the string INTO.

if you want your own model to have lower case words, simply define your model as such.

so it becomes

```
[JsonProperty("reference")]
public string reference {get;set;}
```

This however violates normal naming convention that states Properties should start with upper case letters.

or, use the

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
```

Annotation instead, that should actually resolve what you want.

Comment: `[JsonProperty = "some name"]` is invalid syntax. Also, the [JsonProperty] you propose is exactly what they have already. And finally, this is not about renaming the C# properties.

Comment: @PeterB corrected the syntax, however, if it isn't about renaming the properties, I would like the author to be a bit more specific, as I don't see what else it could be about? Or perhaps you could?

"object properties to lower camel case using" qoute from OP, what is it about then?

Comment: They ask "I think I did everything right, but it still isn't working" (and a comment then says "it is working in my fiddle"). I don't have an answer to their issue, but when I see an answer that (IMO) is not correct or does not solve anything then I call it out.

Comment: It's indeed about renaming the properties between JSON and C#. But it's not a "How do I do it?" but "Why isn't this working" question, and you are proposing the exact same thing, OP allegedly already does.

Comment: @derpirscher
I am not proposing what he is doing already, I am highlighting he could violate naming conventions , and change his own model, I am giving him an alternate property type to try and use to achieve the same thing, considering that it SHOULD WORK. It might help him. 

But he has not provided enough code to replicate the result, so your comment is irrelevant?

Comment: There is no need to violate any naming conventions. That's the whole purpose of the `JsonProperty` annotation. You can name your model Properties in C# following whatever convention you want and by defining a `JsonProperty("foobar")` you can name the very same property completely different in the resulting JSON. And that's what OP already do. They try to serialize an uppercase `Reference` from C# to a lowercase `reference` in JSON, using the `JsonProperty("reference")` annotation. Which works fine as the linked fiddle shows.

Comment: @derpirscher https://dotnetfiddle.net/TB63aL
This is not the same syntax. Dude, read the whole answer.

Comment: And yeah, as OPs code fails to reproduce, we should either ask for clarifiation (or vote to close for the respective reason) instead of giving answers that are just guessing.

Comment: @derpirscher They aren't guessing, they are valid solutions that will ALSO work.